# Difficulty of shifting down to 1st while moving (manual)

Tags: manual-transmission, gears, skoda, estelle

The gearbox from the car I'm rebuilding (Skoda Estelle '72, rear mounted engine, RWD, manual transmission) has the following problem:

- I can shift up/down with engine off
- I can shift up/down with engine on, car static, by keeping clutch pressed
- I can shift up to any gear while running
- I can shift down to from any gear while running EXCEPT engaging 1st

When I want to shift say from 2nd to 1st while running, I can't without "rasping" the 1st pinion a lot, like this gearbox has a "direct" 1st. I'm discarding clutch problems, since otherwise every gear would have such problems. I tend to think it is something with the 1st/2nd synchro. My question is: would it be its friction rings?

What else can yield that symptom?

**UPDATE:**

Reading its Haynes manual it says "Synchromesh: on all forward gears". So it implies 1st gets synchronized, right? In my case, it is almost impossible to get back to 1st without almost stopping the car.

[image]

**UPDATE (July 10th, 2017):**

Yes...it has synchromesh. I wonder which component of it, on this design, could make the issue (impossible to shift 2nd to 1st while moving)

[image]

Comment: On every manual I've ever driven, its pretty hard to shift to first in motion.  Do you mean moving or engine running but car stationary?  I know we have a question about this somewhere, I'll try to find it.

Comment: The purpose of first gear is to move of from stationary.  Why would you want to shift to first whilst the vehicle is still in motion?

Comment: @SteveMatthews It's really annoying to be forced to come to a standstill to be able to engage in 1st gear. And while driving traffic jams speeds(5-10km/h), it's not quick to try and drive off in 2nd gear, or you have to abuse your clutch. That is, in many older cars, with the older 4 gear transmissions.

Comment: Might I suggest you learn to double declutch, more info here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_clutch_(technique)

Answer (score 6):

There's much older cars that don't have their 1st gear synchronised. My '76 Triumph TR7 doesn't have it, and I bet your Skoda doesn't have it either. You either have to come to a complete standstill before you can engage 1st gear, or you'd have to double declutch. The latter requires quite some exercise to master. Reverse gear isn't synchronised in much (older) cars either, not even in all today's cars.

**Edit:** Since @Chenmunka confirmed that it's very plausible that this is your problem, i felt it's useful to elaborate somewhat about double declutching.
I was really annoyed by the fact that i couldn't engage in first gear while rolling, especially in traffic jams it's really frustrating.

Double declutching in 1st gear is a lot easier than at higher speeds. (and i assume here that no one engages 1st gear while driving highway speeds)

You have to declutch, put the transmission into neutral, then you let go off the clutch again. Now comes a bit of feeling and experience into play.

Rev up the engine a little higher than you'd expect the engine to run when you would have been engaged in 1st gear. When in 2nd gear, you usualy have to rev about 1.5 times as high. If you've done well, the clutch now spins a little faster than the engine. As soon as you declutch, the clutch's speed will decrease, causing it to eventually run exactly as fast as the engine.(after half a second or so) Then you can engage in 1st gear. The more you exercise, the faster it'll go.

Comment: I can confirm this.  I used to have a '71 Skoda S100 which is the same engine/gearbox as the Estelle.  There is no synchromesh on 1st or Reverse.

Comment: So what you're telling the OP is: *Not being able to easily shift into first from second is normal*, right? Also, there is a 1st to 2nd synchro, but it doesn't work both ways. If you look at the diagram, I think it's #28.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yeah that's about it. 'not easily' being defined as 'you have to double declutch or come to a complete standstill'. Second gear is synchronised, so shifting to 2nd from any gear, even reverse, will be smooth. This counts also for 3rd and 4th gear. Shifting to 1st from any gear won't be smooth. Much really old cars with a 3 gear box(30s era) only had their second gear synchronised, because you come along that gear the most.

Comment: Good answer, but I would also say that with more recent cars, it is more probable that the first gear synchro is worn than being unsynchronized. None of the manual transmission cars I have driven allow easy engagement of 1st at speed, even though all had the 1st gear synchronized. Strangely enough, one (a 2011 Toyota Yaris) did crunching sounds when attempting double-declutching.

Comment: @juhist The 1st gear synchro being worn sounds very unlikely to me. You barely use that gear and it's synchro ring even less. I think the reason that 1st gear is hard to engage while driving in many cars, is that the synchro needs spin up the clutch such an awful lot. That's because the 1st ratio is so incredible high in relation to the others. In older gearboxes, you'll feel a similar resistance when shifting to second from high speeds.

Comment: Reading its Haynes manual it says "Synchromesh: on all forward gears". So it implies 1st gets synchronized, right? In my case, it is almost impossible to get back to 1st without almost stopping the car.

Comment: @AramAlvarez It's possible the Haynes manual is incorrect. But even if it is correct and 1st is synchronized on your particular car, it doesn't change the high ratio of 1st gear requiring a large change in speed to allow the gear to engage. In case you're unfamiliar with how synchromesh works, here's a decent video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM4CuWlnJY0

Comment: @AramAlvarez One thing I will mention is that, to the best of my understanding, most (all?) gearboxes don't actually allow the baulk ring of the synchromesh to actually directly contact the main gear. Under normal operation (i.e. when the gearbox is installed in the car and filled with gear oil), the viscosity of the oil between the baulk ring and the main gear is what causes the baulk ring to speed up, *not* direct metal-to-metal contact of the ring to the conical section of the main gear...

Comment: @AramAlvarez ...When trying to engage 1st, since the gear is spinning much faster than the output shaft (because of the typically high ratio of 1st gear), it takes much longer for the 1st gear synchro to match the speed of the input shaft with the speed of the 1st gear. For this reason, it is generally very difficult to shift into first while moving, unless you double-clutch (described in Bart's answer quite well). When you double-clutch, you are "manually" matching the speeds of the input and output shaft, at least close enough for the synchronizer ring to make up the rest of the difference.

Comment: I have the same problem on my 1998 Honda Civic. First gear is definitely synchronized but it does not like to shift into first while moving. I think it's because first gear is such a low ratio. You can push hard on the shifter to force it into first. When I do that I can hear the clutch and gears spin up before it pops into gear. I consider this pretty normal behavior. I hardly ever use first except from a stop or in slow traffic.

Comment: @AramAlvarez You can verify if all your gears are indeed synchronised. If they are, it could be that the 1st gear's synchro is worn out, but that doesn't have to be the case. It can still be hard to engage in 1st, because those older tranmissions had way smaller synchrorings than the transmissions of today. Shamtam's comment gives a nice additional explanation of that. I'd also recommend you to study the principle of synchromesh gearboxes. It's really interesting.